# In storyboard UIScrollview not working properly with autoresizing. how to manage without code?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uiscrollview

In storyboard when i am using UIScrollview then its not working properly in autoresizing. To solve my issue , I declare contentsize of scrollview in code then its working fine for me . Is there any way to manage this problem from storyboard?

Comment: i did not face any issue . i just want to know is it possible to manage only storyboard without doing anything in code.

Comment: You can add height constraint to your contentView, then put priority 250, it will stop the error from storyboard while maintain the dynamic height if have

Comment: inner view of the scroll view needs 6 constraints to satisfy. you should play with height constraint of the inner view of scroll view.

Answer (score 1):

When using a scrollview always remember to add a UIView as a contentView and add all the subviews to the contentView and you need to make sure ALL subviews are pinned to all 4 sides. Your bottom most view needs to be pinned to the bottom of the contentView for the scrollview to work as it should.

A good quick tutorial on this is in: https://www.natashatherobot.com/ios-autolayout-scrollview/